# Run a shell command via QProcess on Android Platform

Tags: android, qt, qprocess

I cannot run any command via QProcess on Android platform. I am using Qt library. Can anyone explain how to run shell commands from my application on Android platform ?

```
    QProcess process();

    process.execute("ls");

   bool finished = process.waitForFinished(-1);

   qDebug() <<  "End : " << finished << " Output : " << process.errorString();
```

The process doesn't finish if I don't specify timeout. process.waitForFinished() returns false when I specify timeout let's say 10000 ms.

Comment: Anyone can help ?

Comment: Can you explain what is wrong? Like what are the values of `QProcess::error()`, `errorString()`, `exitCode()`, `exitStatus()`, etc. after the process has finished.

Comment: it doesn't finish, just waits

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your example code is faulty and it will not work on ANY platform!
`ls` command is not an exactable! This command is build into a shell program for example `bash`.

Another bug in your code is that `QProcess::execute` is a [static function](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#execute).
So final line doesn't have impact on process you have tried to start.

So your code should look like this:

```
QProcess process;
process.start("bash", QStringList() << "-c" << "ls");

bool finished = process.waitForFinished(-1);
```

Comment: I tried your code with process.start("bash", QStringList() << "-c" << "ls"); but it doesn't end. It runs on ubuntu without a problem but it doesn't run on android

Comment: question is: does Android has a `bash`? Check this with `adb`. And if it has it: do you have capability to run it (if it is needed)? Now you should take a look on logs and see what kind of error information is printed.

Comment: `ls`is not a built in function, see bash documentation: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html

Comment: I solved it, the problem was about breakpoints. When I run program without debugging mode it ran but now I need to run a binary file. It can be run from adb shell like ./<programname> but I don't know how to run with QProcess

Answer (score 1):

You are using `QProcess::execute()` which is a static function. Quoting [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#execute-1): "*Starts the program command in a new process, waits for it to finish*".

So what could happen in your code is:

```
QProcess process();

process.execute("ls"); // Start "ls" and wait for it to finish
// "ls" has finished
bool finished = process.waitForFinished(-1); // Wait for the process to finish, but there is no process and you could get locked here forever...
```

There are 2 ways to fix your code:

```
QProcess process();

process.start("ls"); // Start "ls" and returns

bool finished = process.waitForFinished(-1);

qDebug() <<  "End : " << finished << " Output : " << process.errorString();
```

or

```
 QProcess::execute("ls");
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the result is same. It doesn't end, just waits

Comment: I've done some tests. Qt does not seem to lock waiting for a non existant process and the examples I gave you work fine on desktop and on Android. The problem can simply be that "ls" doesn't stop. I've seen cases like that on Debian where a process is accessing the file system and prevent other processes from accessing it, the other processes would the be stuck.